# Error: Access is Denied coming in response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis

I have this code

```
$.ajax({
    url: sServiceURL + 'submitData',
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify(selectedData),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
}).done(function (data) {

}).fail(function (status) {

})
```

As it is a get request, so I entered the same URL on in the browser and when I hit enter, I am getting correct response. But when I try using jquery, the request fails and error response contains: Error: Access is denied

Comment: Not clear!! Can you explain more!!??

Comment: In browser, means what? Not getting what you want to say. Please explain.

Comment: Please add full error stack trace.

Comment: As it is a get request, so I entered the same URL on in the browser and when I hit enter, I am getting correct response. But when I try using jquery, the request fails and error response contains: Error: Access is denied

Comment: at least provide the URL...

Comment: The server is not publicly accessible.

Comment: it sounds like a [CORS issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)...

Comment: Actually it is a office App using js and when I host the service on the server and redirects the App to that service, it is giving this error in response

Comment: you can try removing `contentType` property as when you hit using browser data is not being set as `json`... again thats just a wild guess.

Comment: I checked almost all the solutions given on internet related to CORS but not working